# Using a <label> element with the for attribute on ngTagsInput

Tags: ng-tags-input

Using [ng-tags-input](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) works well, but I have a `<label for="my-field">` which doesn't work. The actual `input` element inside the `ng-tags-input` element has no name or id attribute, so I can't target it with the `for` attribute. Is there something I'm missing or do I have to use custom JavaScript to get it to behave like a regular label in a browser where clicking on the label focuses the field?

Here's a plunkr showing the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/D3OLro?p=preview

The first input can be focused by clicking the label, but not the ng-tags-input